# My jQuery Ajax Call to pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I asked about 5 month ago about rewriting my ajax call in pure Javascript. Here the original post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35415812/need-help-to-rewrite-my-jquery-ajax-call-to-plain-javascript

I never thought about to rewrite the script completely because it works  but now i need to rewrite the whole script to plain js. I already startet.
Here is the jQUery/JS mix:

```
    var cc = document.getElementsByClassName("cart-count");
    var wc = document.getElementsByClassName("wishlist-count");     
    var url = wp_ajax.ajax_url;
    var data = {
        action: 'get_counts'    
    };
    // JQUERY JS mixed VERSION
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            var counts = JSON.parse(data);

            console.log(data);

            for(var i = 0; i < cc.length; i++){
                cc[i].innerText=counts["cartCount"];
            }
            for(var i = 0; i < wc.length; i++){
                wc[i].innerText=counts["wlCount"];
            }

        }
    });
```

console says:

```
    {"cartCount":"(1)","wlCount":"(3)"}
```

That's right!

But now i tried to rewrite the rest. Here the latest:

```
    var cc = document.getElementsByClassName("cart-count");
    var wc = document.getElementsByClassName("wishlist-count");
    var url = wp_ajax.ajax_url;
    var data = {
        action: 'get_counts'    
    };
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                //document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML =     xmlhttp.responseText;
                var counts = data
                console.log(data);
                for(var i = 0; i < cc.length; i++){
                    cc[i].innerText=counts["cartCount"]; 
                }
                for(var i = 0; i < wc.length; i++){
                    wc[i].innerText=counts["wlCount"];  
                }

                console.log('done');

            } else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
                console.log('There was an error 400');
            } else {
                console.log('something else other than 200 was returned');
            }
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open('POST', url, true);
    xmlhttp.send(data);
```

It does't work. The console gives me not the value, just the var:

```
    Object {action: "get_counts"}
```

My question/problem: How can i get the data action values without the jQuery ajax? Please no questions like "why not jQuery?".

Thanks for all help!!! Sorry for my english.

UPDATE:
I got it!

jQuery:

```
 var data = {
    action: 'get_counts'    
 };
```

JS:

```
 url + '?action=get_counts'
```

Comment: Can you tell us `console.log(typeof data);`

Comment: Try with `var counts = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: Ok i tried with var counts = JSON.parse(data);
console.log: VM3089:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);//you have to parse result
```

before this

```
            var counts = data
            console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not evaluating the AJAX response data, but the local variable `data` which is set above the AJAX call:

```
var data = {
    action: 'get_counts'    
};
```

You need to parse the AJAX response instead:

```
if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    console.log( JSON.parse(xmlhttp.response) )
}
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/response

Answer (score 0):

Its happening because Ajax is async request which the browser handers in a different thread than the one which is processing your code. Normally jquery and other similar frameworks have callback methods defined for that but in pure JS implementation you can use

> xmlhttp.responseText

to fetch the output once the request is done